# Index of / in Laravel cPanel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I am facing issue "Index of /" while accessing my website that i have uploaded on cPanel direct root. Even I have .htaccess file in public_html

I try this htaccess code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f



RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you upload the Laravel to `public_html`? Because thats not where Laravel should be installed. The core files need to be outside of that folder. set your domain root to the Laravel `public` folder.

Comment: Yes i uploaded my project in public_html. All folders in public_html

Comment: That's not good for the security of your application. In cPanel you can set the root (public) folder for your domain. Install Laravel in a folder outside of `public_html` and set the domain root to the laravel public folder

Comment: But how i can set it easily?

Comment: cpanel -> domains -> Manage -> set the document Root. seems quite easy?

Comment: Yes i did it same as it is but Actually i am unable to access my public folder which is in public_html

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable indexing your paths from htaccess. Add this line to htaccess above:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f



RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks Tural for answering but where i have need to put it on top of htaccess?

Comment: Yes, it will be put top on htaccess

Comment: If it helped you, please come back

Comment: Is that enough bro?
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: I changed my htaccess code . Please show them.

Comment: Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f



RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>

Comment: Dude look above pls. I changed my codes.

Comment: Yes I did but unfortunately, having same issue

Comment: Check it: <IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
 Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

Comment: ok bro let me check it

Comment: check please bro )

Comment: Sorry for late replying bro. Still having same issue bro

Comment: I think for this, need to look personally. Maybe, there are other issues.

Comment: Actually I want to upload my project on direct domain public_html the folder where i put all my project. But cannot access public folder via htaccess

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```